# iPhone Mach-O binaries, string storage, __TEXT/__DATA

Tags: iphone, c, binary, constants, mach-o

I am attempting to read constant (or initilization) strings from an iPhone Mach-O binary file. I understand that the 3 relevant segment.sections are _*TEXT.*_cstring _*TEXT.*_ustring and _*DATA.*_cfstring. Howver, even though I know the string information is stored in these three blocks of data, which I have extracted, I can not make any sense of it, and it all looks like garbage - I do not see any recognizable character strings. Can anyone shed some light on this and give me an idea of what steps need to be take to read the string data?

I have looked at some code (GetAddrOfConstantCFString() from http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp), but again, couldn't quite relate it to what I see in the binaries.

In my case the sizes of the sections in question are:

```
__TEXT.__cstring (99 K-bytes)
__TEXT.__ustring (<200 bytes)
__DATA.__cfstring (29 K-bytes)
```

To give you an idea, the first 32 bytes of the __cfstring section, which I though would contain the actual strings looks like this:

Dump _*DATA.*_cfstring

```
00  00  00  00  c8  07  00  00  74  02  0d  00  15  00  00  00
00  00  00  00  c8  07  00  00  8c  02  0d  00  01  00  00  00
...
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thinking its targeted for iPhone, that might be compressed somehow.

Comment: I think the `__cfstring` section would contain object data only, which means it would have pointers the the `__cstring` section, which then contains the raw string characters.

Comment: **ughoavgfhw**, that sounds very plausible, and would explain why __cstring is larger than the other sections.

The issue is that the __cstring data looks like garbage. I was trying to decode it as if it was UTF-16, but it didn't produce a single normal character string.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've found the answer.

1) the files are generally encrypted (this can be tested with otool -l prog_file|grep -i crypt ). Not all sections are encrypted but usually the first block including _*TEXT.*_text (prog code) and _*TEXT.*_cstring are. The _*DATA.*_cfstring section was not encrypted in my case.

2) as expected __cfstring consists of 16-byte structures (NSConstantString), where the 3rd word is a pointer to memory where _*TEXT.*_cstring is loaded. The 4th word is the length.

So in real life the trick is to decrypt the file first, and then all is visible and accessible. I still didn't get around doing it properly, but dumped a piece of memory in gdb, which then replaced the relevant section in the file.